# jquery load and unload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two links lets say link 1 and link 2. When user clicks on any of them it loads separate html page dynamically using jquery load function. It works fine but what I want is to when user clicks on link 1 then it first unload the previous page which is already in a container div. I am currently using `empty()` function but it does not work the way I want it. How can I achieve this?

**Update**

"It doesn't work the way I want it" = What I mean is it loads the same page on top of the current one. I know this because when I press lets say `profile` then it loads `profile.html` in container div. Inside profile.html I have two buttons and I attached a click event on them so when I click on these buttons it shows alert() message once. Then when I press on `home`, it loads `home.html`. Then again when I press on profile which loads profile.html again. So now if I press buttons inside profile.html it shows alert() message twice when I click each button once

Here is my code

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#" rel="home" class="home tabs"></a></li>
 <li><a href="#" rel="camera" class="profile tabs"></a></li>
 <li><a href="#" rel="profile" class="cam tabs"></a></li>
</ul>
```

here is my js

```
init: function () {
Tabs.loadViews('home');
$(document).on('touchstart', 'footer a', Tabs.getViewName);
));
}

loadViews: function ( page ) {
    var view = './views/' + page + '.html';
$(container).unload().empty();
$(container).load(view, function () {
setTimeout(function () {
    scroller.refresh();
}, 0);
 });
}
```

Comment: "it does not work the way I want it", expand on this.

Comment: I found my mistake. It is working now. Thanks

Comment: @al0neevenings Post your answer here too; When others are facing the same problem, they'll know how you solved it.

Comment: just do this $(container).html(""); before calling loading data